# The list of all the launched sites uses both "12 months" and "1 year"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange

The similar issue was noticed and fixed earlier for the [user profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61489/member-for-1-year-12-months).

But it still can be seeing on the StackExchange ["All Sites"](https://stackexchange.com/sites) page. I almost sure that is was already submitted here, but i cannot find any question about this. And, yes,  I understand that 12 months are most likely 11 months with some additional  days, and 1 year is 1 year with some additional days, but when you see it on the screen, it looks a little bit odd.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed.  We now display 11 months, never 12.

Answer (score 7):

Stack Exchange rounds to approximate dates.

So if this were a user page then if you'd been a member for 11 months and 20 days (say) it rounds it up to "12 months".

It doesn't say "1 year" because that has a [special meaning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/13/yearling) and so would be confusing as well as inaccurate.

So it will say "12 months" when you've been a member for more than 11 months and less than 1 year and "1 year" when you've been a member for more than 12 months.

I assume the same logic applies to site pages. There is some rounding and a year does have special meaning.

Comment: This doesn't look like a rounding issue. I think it's just like the question author purports in being the same issue as with profile fields. The only 2 sites with "12 months" were launched on July 26th and July 28th respectively, and today is July 25th which is within the 5 day window between 360 days (12 30-day periods) and 365 days (an actual year). If rounding were the case, Money (launched on August 4th, 10 days from now) should be showing 12 months, but it is showing 11 months. The fix will probably be the same thing waffles did last time.

Comment: I don't want to change 12 month to 1 year(because of all `special meaning`). I prefer Waffles's solution from question I linked to: "if (months > 11) months = 11"