# 12 months should be equal to 1 year in question's activity

Tags: bug, dates

Why am I seeing `12 months` instead of `1 year` for some question's activity?

> [image: 12 months]

> [image: 1 year]

Possibly there is a rounding issue. I think it should be fixed.

To find such posts you can use `created` search options with dates in the interval of 12 - 13 months ago or use [this search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=lastactive%3A13m..12m) though not all will be 12 months.

Comment: Very much related: [Member for 12 months?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109043/member-for-12-months)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think the answer will be [exact the same](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109058/339911).

Comment: With smaller team and lots of more urgent things to do (aka Channels) I am not sure. But we can always hope.

Comment: @ShadowWizard seems someone from the Team already downvoted :)

Comment: Who once said "always fix bugs before writing new code"?

Comment: Also potentially related: [The list of all the launched sites uses both "12 months" and "1 year"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99748/335251)