# Chat message posted "24h ago"?

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars

[image]

Does anyone know what went wrong??? Why isn't it ***1d*** ago but ***24h*** ago? Look, there's another message above it that reads *1d ago* which is correct.

Comment: I think here is the same root as in [another date issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304327/339911). Possibly duplicate.

Comment: Not a bug, and even if it is, it won't be fixed. [Similar report I made](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301468/24-hours-should-become-1-day) got score of -10 and auto deleted. ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoU7c.png).) Pretty sure there were more similar reports, all downvoted and deleted by now. :)

Comment: I'd guess because of rounding: >23 hours → 24 hours, but >24 hours (1 day) → 1 day.