# Member for 12 months?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, timestamps

I have seen [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61489/member-for-1-year-12-months), which has been marked with the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but I am still experiencing it*:

[image: Screenshot from Stack Overflow Profile, says 12 months]

Or, is it a new bug?

**<sub>* If it is not clear, I am a member for 12 months, but not for 1 year</sub>**

Comment: For what it's worth, I can repro this, so it's not limited to users viewing their own profiles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will be fixed on the next push.  Again :)

Answer (score 4):

You registered your account at oct 15. So you have to wait another 4 days for this badge.

The number of months is rounded up. But the year is an exact match.

And due to some distortions in the space time continuum, 12 months <= 1 year.

Comment: Well, waffles's answer at the linked question does say "We will no longer display weird 1 year and 12 months for the last five days of your year."

Comment: It's not that the number of months is rounded up, it's that each month is exactly 30 days.

Comment: *And due to some distortions in the space time continuum, 12 months <= 1 year.* => So, you agree it is a bug ;)