# Error rounding up number of views

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, views

There is an error in number of views for questions that have number of views between 1500 and 2000 (most likely for number of views in the range xx500-xx999).

Next image shows 2 kviews for 1507 views :
[image: 2 kviews for 1507 views]

Comment: By design. Lots of numbers on this site are rounded. Users with 19,951 rep show up as "20k."

Comment: @PopularDemand I thought it was something like this : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109043/member-for-12-months

Answer (score 3):

That's not an error, it's called rounding.

Comment: That's one strange rounding. I expected to see 2kviews at 2000+ views

Comment: @VJo, you're thinking of *floor*.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Right. That's what I expected (not rounding)