# Question view counter: different values displayed

Tags: discussion, bug, views

I made a question in Stack Overflow that has just scored 1500 views. But, while the "main" counter passed from 1K to 2k, the tooltip displays 1527 (the actual value I guess). Is it a round matter? Is this correct?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrong view count for questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14119/282094)  by design, other duplicates:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109559/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208006/282094   https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90187/282094

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume so. The same behavior of rounding up numbers can be seen for reputation in the user card once that user reaches double digit thousands...

- If I have 13,364 rep, it'll show as 13.4K
- If I have 13,501 rep, it'll show as 13.5K

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you have 13,450 it is show as 13.5k. It's the 50 free reputation giveaway, every 100 rep.

Answer (score 0):

this is how its looks like when there is four digit

[image]

so they rounding up numbers and than it will look like

[image]

and lix explained how rounding number works here