# Bad rounding for months on stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, reputation-leagues, math-se

> member for: 1 year, 12 months

e.g. https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/quarter/stackoverflow/2011-10-01/220643#220643

There's a [similar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61489/member-for-1-year-12-months) question but the first answer says it was fixed (more than one year ago, or should I say 12 months ;-). I suspect the same code pattern exists in other places and needs the same fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed now. You were right – stackexchange.com needed the same fix that the Q&A sites got. Thanks.