# Careers is missing the good parts

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, amazon

I have the [Crockford Bible](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596517742) in my Careers CV reading list. In the search result when adding a book, as well as in the edit view, the book title is displayed correctly:

[image: edit view with the correct title]

However in the final rendered version, both on the CV editing page and the public display, the title is stripped down to just "JavaScript":

[image: rendered view with the truncated title]

Comment: It’s by design, but the design needs to be better. [Here’s](http://www.amazon.com/Joel-Software-Occasionally-Developers-Designers/dp/1590593898%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIIBINOD46VC3JCLQ%26tag%3Dstackoverfl08-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3D1590593898) why we started splitting titles by colon. Fix on the way…

Comment: Excellent, that means we can blame Joel!

Comment: "if the book title contains a colon, and its author is Joel Spolsky, split it."

Comment: @Pekka Don't joke, [they'll do it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67929/145982)