# Pluralization bug in "member for" area on profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, plurals

I think the picture pretty much explains it all.  Not sure if this is the case for all SE sites, but this is from Stack Overflow.

[image: profile-page bug]

Comment: ["Dear Next Person Who Opens a Pluralization 'Bug', I will personally come to your house and bludgeon you to death with a giant S" -- Jeff Atwood](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105)

Comment: lol, that's hilarious. I'm not sure how to take that...

Comment: Well Steve, it was nice knowing you.

Comment: @SteveP. In short, there are pluralization problems all over and they don't really care, for whatever reason

Comment: They don't care because there are always [bigger fish to fry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192086).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Perhaps it's not a huge deal, but I find it to be pretty annoying.  It can't take that long to fix, can it?  I understand them not going through code and outright searching for these errors, but I would hope that they would want them reported.

Comment: @SteveP. History has proven that the answer to that one is "not really".

Comment: @Bart Well, that's unfortunate.

Comment: Strangely, back when it used to say "[1 year, 12 months](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61489/member-for-1-year-12-months)", it did do it right

Comment: @RobertHarvey By that logic, SE should do *absolutely nothing about anything* until they've figured out how to prevent the eventual heat-death of the universe (or scientifically proven that it's not going to happen and we don't have to do anything). Oh, and seeing through the continuation of humanity beyond the red dwarfism of our Sun in a couple billion years, which is coming up Real Soon Now(™).

Comment: @somequixotic: Epic straw man.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That was the idea. :-)

Comment: The time saved not having to process these posts would probably more than offset the time it would take to stick `(year == 1) ? "year" : "years"` in a file somewhere

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: You're forgetting about the design meeting.  And the design pre-meeting. And the scheduling meeting for the design meeting and pre-meeting.  And the code review and...

Comment: @RobertHarvey At least he's not forgetting about the Validation / Integration environment deployment, waiting for manual/automated tests to be run, and then staging it to deploy. Production **is** the test environment for SE. With our luck they'd reverse the ternary values and say "2 year" and "1 years", with a rare side effect that makes Jon Skeet's profile say he's been a member for NaN years. Then it would take another NaN years to get a new feature-request approved to flip the ternary return values.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - this kind of issue will be handled automatically as part of localization. (yes, I am a tease, I know).

Comment: @somequixotic - actually, Meta is our test environment ;)

Comment: Which is why, when you're on Meta, your computer can sometimes suddenly reset without wa

Comment: @Oded you mean it will show up as "שנה אחת, שני חודשים"? :-P

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Strangely, Hebrew is not a priority ;) Even the [area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40770/stackoverflow-in-hebrew) looks rather... slow.

Comment: @Oded never noticed that proposal! Oh well, guess it's never too late. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Even if it goes through, I can imagine that we will need another round of localization. Yay bidi ;)

Comment: [Jeff Atwood's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Atwood) *Big-S* is an official meme: [Pluralization Bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791) (from [The Many Memes of Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478)).